# Read data using customized schema

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have pipe delimited file with no headers and want to read into Spark.

The data looks like:

```
100005072756|R|OTHER|8|125000|360|11/2000|01/2001|95|95|1|29|694|N|P|SF|1|P|MI|492|30|FRM||1|N
100006905529|C|FLAGSTAR BANK, FSB|7.875|99000|360|12/2000|02/2001|80|80|1|55|689|N|C|SF|1|P|CA|923||FRM|||N
100010275736|R|JPMORGAN CHASE BANK, NA|7.625|140000|360|12/2000|02/2001|21|21|1|12|796|N|R|SF|1|P|CO|803||FRM|||N
100015654434|B|FLAGSTAR BANK, FSB|7.625|102000|360|03/2001|05/2001|80|80|2|32|706|N|C|SF|1|P|WI|541||FRM|661||N
100020827204|R|OTHER|7.125|214000|360|01/2001|03/2001|80|80|1|43|731|N|P|SF|4|P|IL|604||FRM|||N
100027347659|R|OTHER|8|195000|360|12/2000|02/2001|74|74|2|42|720|N|C|SF|1|P|VA|236||FRM|696||N
100037532932|R|BANK OF AMERICA, N.A.|7.75|228000|360|12/2000|02/2001|95|95|2|38|642|N|P|SF|1|P|AL|352|30|FRM|664|2|N
100040777887|C|CITIMORTGAGE, INC.|7|145000|360|01/2001|03/2001|71|71|2|20|752|N|P|SF|1|P|CA|953||FRM|786||N
100041189347|R|FLEET NATIONAL BANK|7.875|150000|240|10/2000|12/2000|85|85|2|34|734|N|C|SF|1|P|CO|810|6|FRM||1|N
100043437231|R|JPMORGAN CHASE BANK, NA|6.875|275000|240|12/2000|02/2001|71|71|1|41|765|N|P|PU|1|P|VA|201||FRM|||N
```

This is the code I use:

```py
origSchema = StructType([
                         StructField("loan_id", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("origination_channel", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("seller_name", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("original_interest_rate", DoubleType(), True),
                         StructField("original_upb", DoubleType(), True),
                         StructField("original_loan_term", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("origination_date", DateType(), True),
                         StructField("first_payment_date", DateType(), True),
                         StructField("original_ltv", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("original_cltv", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("number_of_borrowers", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("original_dti", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("borrower_fico_at_origination", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("first_time_home_buyer_indicator", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("loan_purpose", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("property_type", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("number_of_units", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("occupancy_type", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("property_state", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("zip_code_short", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("primary_mortgage_insurance_percent", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("product_type", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("coborrower_fico_at_origination", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("mortgage_insurance_type", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("relocation_mortgage_indicator", StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.read.load("/mnt/mi-sa-armor/INPUT/FANNIEMAE/2001Q1/Acquisition_2001Q1.txt", format="csv", sep="|", header="false", schema=origSchema)
```

By checking the dataframe:

```py
+-------+-------------------+-----------+----------------------+------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+------------+-------------+-------------------+------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------------+------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
|loan_id|origination_channel|seller_name|original_interest_rate|original_upb|original_loan_term|origination_date|first_payment_date|original_ltv|original_cltv|number_of_borrowers|original_dti|borrower_fico_at_origination|first_time_home_buyer_indicator|loan_purpose|property_type|number_of_units|occupancy_type|property_state|zip_code_short|primary_mortgage_insurance_percent|product_type|coborrower_fico_at_origination|mortgage_insurance_type|relocation_mortgage_indicator|
+-------+-------------------+-----------+----------------------+------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+------------+-------------+-------------------+------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------------+------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
|   null|               null|       null|                  null|        null|              null|            null|              null|        null|         null|               null|        null|                        null|                           null|        null|         null|           null|          null|          null|          null|                              null|        null|                          null|                   null|                         null|
|   null|               null|       null|                  null|        null|              null|            null|              null|        null|         null|               null|        null|                        null|                           null|        null|         null|           null|          null|          null|          null|                              null|        null|                          null|                   null|                         null|
|   null|               null|       null|                  null|        null|              null|            null|              null|        null|         null|               null|        null|                        null|                           null|        null|         null|           null|          null|          null|          null|                              null|        null|                          null|                   null|                         null|
|   null|               null|       null|                  null|        null|              null|            null|              null|        null|         null|               null|        null|                        null|                           null|        null|         null|           null|          null|          null|          null|                              null|        null|                          null|                   null|                         null|
|   null|               null|       null|                  null|        null|              null|            null|              null|        null|         null|               null|        null|                        null|                           null|        null|         null|           null|          null|          null|          null|                              null|        null|                          null|                   null|                         null|
+-------+-------------------+-----------+----------------------+------------+------------------+----------------+------------------+------------+-------------+-------------------+------------+----------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+-------------+---------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------------+------------+------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

It didn't seem I have read them correctly.

But if I removed schema option, it is just fine but since the raw data didn't have headers, the dataframe didn't look as expected.

```py
df = spark.read.load("/mnt/mi-sa-armor/INPUT/FANNIEMAE/2001Q1/Acquisition_2001Q1.txt", format="csv", sep="|", header="false")
```

```py
+------------+---+--------------------+-----+------+---+-------+-------+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|         _c0|_c1|                 _c2|  _c3|   _c4|_c5|    _c6|    _c7|_c8|_c9|_c10|_c11|_c12|_c13|_c14|_c15|_c16|_c17|_c18|_c19|_c20|_c21|_c22|_c23|_c24|
+------------+---+--------------------+-----+------+---+-------+-------+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|100005072756|  R|               OTHER|    8|125000|360|11/2000|01/2001| 95| 95|   1|  29| 694|   N|   P|  SF|   1|   P|  MI| 492|  30| FRM|null|   1|   N|
|100006905529|  C|  FLAGSTAR BANK, FSB|7.875| 99000|360|12/2000|02/2001| 80| 80|   1|  55| 689|   N|   C|  SF|   1|   P|  CA| 923|null| FRM|null|null|   N|
|100010275736|  R|JPMORGAN CHASE BA...|7.625|140000|360|12/2000|02/2001| 21| 21|   1|  12| 796|   N|   R|  SF|   1|   P|  CO| 803|null| FRM|null|null|   N|
|100015654434|  B|  FLAGSTAR BANK, FSB|7.625|102000|360|03/2001|05/2001| 80| 80|   2|  32| 706|   N|   C|  SF|   1|   P|  WI| 541|null| FRM| 661|null|   N|
|100020827204|  R|               OTHER|7.125|214000|360|01/2001|03/2001| 80| 80|   1|  43| 731|   N|   P|  SF|   4|   P|  IL| 604|null| FRM|null|null|   N|
+------------+---+--------------------+-----+------+---+-------+-------+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Can you please help me to trouble shoot my code why it didn't load the data correctly when using customized schema?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your date formatted columns that are killing it. Set those to StringType instead and then fix them after you have the dataframe. It's not going to be able to parse your dates without more information.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
origSchema = StructType([
                         StructField("loan_id", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("origination_channel", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("seller_name", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("original_interest_rate", DoubleType(), True),
                         StructField("original_upb", DoubleType(), True),
                         StructField("original_loan_term", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("origination_date", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("first_payment_date", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("original_ltv", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("original_cltv", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("number_of_borrowers", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("original_dti", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("borrower_fico_at_origination", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("first_time_home_buyer_indicator", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("loan_purpose", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("property_type", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("number_of_units", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("occupancy_type", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("property_state", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("zip_code_short", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("primary_mortgage_insurance_percent", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("product_type", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("coborrower_fico_at_origination", IntegerType(), True),
                         StructField("mortgage_insurance_type", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("relocation_mortgage_indicator", StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.read.option("inferSchema", True).option("sep", "|").format("csv").load("/path/to/data/name_of_file.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

When schema is enforced, spark is returning null values for records that are not based on given schema.

There are 3 modes of parsing files in spark csv:

By default it is `PERMISSIVE`. Possible values are:

1. `PERMISSIVE`: try to parse all lines: nulls are inserted for missing
   tokens and extra tokens are ignored. If record is malformed then whole record will be set to null values. e.g. data type or format mismatch.
2. `DROPMALFORMED`: drop lines that
   have fewer or more tokens than expected or tokens which do not match
   the schema.
3. `FAILFAST`: abort with a RuntimeException if any malformed
   line is encountered.

You are not setting any mode so getting default behavior.

If you are interested in showing column names correctly then make all columns in Schema to StringType.

Once you see data looks correct then format it (e.g. date columns) and cast it if needed.